# Ansible: How to get the current "host index" when using host ranges in Ansible inventory?

Tags: ansible

Given a `inventory.yml` that is targeting a specific host range, such as this

```
my_role:
  hosts:
   computer-[1:50].com:
     my_role_variable: true
```

suppose I would like to set a variable `my_role_variable_2` that is dependent on the "current iterator" of the host range, for example `computer-42.com` specifically should get the variable `COMPUTER_42`, as in:

```
my_role:
  hosts:
   computer-[1:50].com:
     my_role_variable: true
     my_role_variable_2: "COMPUTER_{{ ?? index ?? }}"
```

given that the special variable `inventory_hostname` exists, I guess I could use things like `regex_search`:

```
my_role:
  hosts:
   computer-[1:50].com:
     my_role_variable: true
     my_role_variable_2: "COMPUTER_{{ inventory_hostname | regex_search('computer-(\d+).com') }}"
```

but surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The filter "regex_replace" should do the job

```
var2: "COMPUTER_{{ inventory_hostname|regex_replace('computer-(\\d+).com', '\\1') }}"
```

Next option would be "split()"

```
var2: "COMPUTER_{{ inventory_hostname.split('.').0.split('-').1 }}"
```